Efficient SQL query with pandas using databricks-sql-python
Databricks allows to make SQL queries via an API using the databricks-sql-python package.
There are then two ways of creating a connection object that can be put into a pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=connection). I'm wondering which one is better in terms of performance and reliability when doing SQL queries from pandas:

Creating Python DB API 2.0 with
from databricks import sql


connection = sql.connect(server_hostname=host, http_path=http_path)

this works but produces the following warning,
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or 
database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 
connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

In the implementation code it looks like they are using pyarrow, which sounds to me like an efficient way of creating pandas DataFrames. The warning is a bit dissuasive though.

The other alternative is to use the SQLAlchemy which has a databricks connector exposed by the same package,
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(f"databricks://<rest of the URL")

This works and gets rids of the warning, but doesn't it imply an extra serialization step to the SQLAlchemy types?


Also asked in databricks-sql-python#476
So in general which one should be used with pandas?

DB API 2.0 gives warning, which implies it is not supported by pandas. SQLAlchemy is officially supported by pandas. But as you said it has serialization step, as it maps the database types to Python types.

Both approaches—using databricks.sql.connect or SQLAlchemy—work for querying Databricks tables into Pandas. The main difference lies in compatibility and the warning you mentioned.
Option 1: Using databricks.sql.connect
This method is a direct connection via Databricks’ SQL connector. It’s fast and efficient, as it uses PyArrow under the hood to handle data transfer. The warning from Pandas about DB API 2.0 support can safely be ignored—it does not affect performance or reliability. If you’re okay with the warning, this is a simple and effective approach.
from databricks import sql
import pandas as pd

connection = sql.connect(
    server_hostname="<your_hostname>",
    http_path="<your_http_path>",
    access_token="<your_token>"
)

query = "SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 10"
df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)

Option 2: Using SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy is a more universal approach and fully supported by Pandas, so you won’t see any warnings. However, it adds a layer of abstraction, which might cause minimal overhead (though likely negligible in most use cases). This is a great choice if you want broader compatibility or cleaner integration with libraries that rely on SQLAlchemy.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("databricks://<your_hostname>/<your_http_path>?access_token=<your_token>")

query = "SELECT * FROM your_table LIMIT 10"
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)

Which One Should You Use?

Go with databricks.sql.connect if you want simplicity and are okay
with ignoring the Pandas warning. Based on our experience, it’s highly reliable and performs well in real-world scenarios.
Use SQLAlchemy if you want a warning-free experience or need
compatibility with other tools that rely on SQLAlchemy.

Both work well—pick the one that fits your needs better!

I would go with SQLAlchemy, it's recommended because it helps to avoid SQL injection if used as it should be.
Also, it helps a lot to solve issues when coding.
